# List/view all checkout files from Sharepoint 2013

Tags: list, list-view, check-out

Is possible each user have a link configured next to "Follow", "Share" ribbon, who shows all the checkout documents by the user?

If so how to do it?

Comment: does it have to be in this location?

Comment: No, I was just thinking there because is easy to get from users, but other locations are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I published now another Step-by-Step guide for "[how to add links to Promoted Actions](https://blog.afrait.com/add-links-to-promoted-actions-sharefollowsync-de/)".

It looks like this:

[image]

It's by now in German but I think you should get it. If not, [let me know](https://blog.afrait.com/contact/) and I do it maybe in english as well.

Comment: Hi Patrick, defenetly is that what Im looking!!
Great! Unfortunately I don't understand German. Can you help me out with that?

Thanks, Ricardo

Comment: Hey Ricardo, your wish comes true. :) I'll post a english version of it tomorrow. I let you all know if it's online.

Comment: English version is now up! (Pictures by now in German / Text in English), pictures will be updated by today! https://blog.afrait.com/ Mark this as the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Now also with pictures in english. Hope you'll get it to work now!

Comment: Brilliant!
Thank you so much!
Ricardo Rebelo

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want some view behind the link like this:

[image]

I achieved this via Content Search Webpart, display template and managed property.

If so, I just published a Step-by-Step guide in my [blog](https://blog.afrait.com). Don't be [afraIT.com](https://afrait.com) to check it out and if it helps to solve your problem please mark this post as the answer.